# How to tell if an object contains an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an Object that is a list of coordinates:

```
var O = {[1,1],[2,1],[3,2]};
```

I need to check the object for a specific coordinate, such as `[1,1]`. How can I do something like:

```
if(O.contains([1,1]))...
```

?

Comment: Your `O` is invalid. It's not an object at all - since it's missing properties. Looks more like a two-dimensional Array to me and should look like `[[1,1],[2,1],[3,2]]`

Comment: Your example code is incorrect in a few ways, namely: objects are in the format of `{key: value, ...}` and equality checks only work on simple values. For the last one there are libraries out there that provide methods for shallow/deep equality checking of objects (arrays are a type of object) and it would be an easy search to find those.

Comment: you can simply match the coords in the array of arrays as a string using regexp or indexOf()

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you would like to compare a nested array.

```js
function contains(array, search) {
    return array.some(function (a) {
        return a.length === search.length && a.every(function (aa, i) {
            return aa === search[i];
        });
    });
}
document.write(contains([[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]], [1, 1]) + '<br>');
document.write(contains([[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]], [1, 1, 1]) + '<br>');
document.write(contains([[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]], [1, 5]) + '<br>');
```